# Secugen sdk not working in xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, java-native-interface, fingerprint

I am trying to use secugen sdk in which I have binded a jar with project. I have added required jar and .so files to project.I have added required .so files by making a lib folder and inside lib folder making sub folders armeabi and x86.
Inside this sub folders I have placed the .so files.At runtime I'm getting exception as follows:

> Java.Lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/fingerprint.fingerprint-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/fingerprint.fingerprint-1/lib/arm,
>   /data/app/fingerprint.fingerprint-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libjnisgfplib.so"

Comment: Follow the guide in the link on how to setup your `.so` libraries : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/using_native_libraries/

Comment: Can you help me to understand the cause of problem

Comment: The cause of the problem is that it's not finding your custom `libjnisgfplib.so` on `armeabi` / `armeabi-v7a` architectures. Make sure you have a proper `.so` for those architectures. Please make sure that you set the proper `Build Action` to these items such as `EmbeddedNativeLibrary` if this is a Xamarin.Android library project and `AndroidNativeLibrary` if it's included in your Xamarin.Android app project.

Comment: In addition to @JonDouglas check that you don't need to call: Java.Lang.JavaSystem.LoadLibrary("jnisgfplib"); in your app before you use the binding.